# proof limits with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$

Tags: limits

1. proof that $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} x \neq 2$ with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ (with definition)

let $\lim\limits_{x \to c}f(x)=L$ so we have for every $\epsilon$ there is a $\delta$ such that $0<|x-c|<\delta => |f(x)-L|< \epsilon$.

2. Can we imply that $0<|x-c|<\delta_1 => |f(x)-L|< \epsilon$ which $\delta_1 < \delta$. (why?)
3. Can we show that $0<|x-c|<\delta => |f(x)-L|< {\epsilon\over a}$. (what can we do with $\epsilon$ ? Can we write $\sqrt{\epsilon}$? why?)

Comment: What you are asking is unclear (there are three numbers and four questions marks). Please explain in words.

Comment: why it's not clear?

Answer (score 0):

If $\epsilon=\dfrac12$,

$$\exists\,\delta:\forall\,0<|x-1|<\delta\implies |x-2|<\dfrac12$$

is false.

Answer (score 0):

For (1): if you take $\epsilon = 1/2$

$$0<|x-1|<\delta_0 => |f(x)-2|< \frac{1}{2}$$

does this $\delta_0$ exist? no becouse we could still take $x=1+\frac{1}{n}$ for some $n$ such that $1/n < \delta_0$, so we have that $|f(1+\frac{1}{n})-2|=|1+\frac{1}{n}-2|=|\frac{1}{n}-1|\ge \frac{1}{2}$ for n large enough.

For (2): if we have that
$$\forall \epsilon >0 \mbox{, }\exists \delta>0 \mbox{ s.t. }0< |x-c|<\delta => |f(x)-L|< \epsilon$$
then taking $0<\delta_1<\delta$, $|x-c|<\delta_1< \delta$. so the definition written above holds for all $x$ such that $|x-c|<\delta_1$.

Finally, for (3): since by definition it holds for all $\epsilon>0$, you can take $\epsilon$ to be whaterer you want.

so if we take $\epsilon_1=\frac{\epsilon}{a}$ for some positive $a$, $\epsilon_1>0$, so the definition holds:

$$0< |x-c|<\delta_1 => |f(x)-L|< \epsilon_1=\frac{\epsilon}{a}$$
taking for example $\delta_1=\frac{\delta}{a}$.

Also, if we select $\epsilon_2=\sqrt{\epsilon}$ for some $\epsilon>0$, $\epsilon_2>0$ again, so the definition still holds:

$$0 < |x-c|<\delta_2 => |f(x)-L|< \epsilon_2=\epsilon_2=\sqrt{\epsilon}$$
taking again the right $\delta_2$.